# OpenId Connect implementation ASP.NET MVC ReturnUrl feature fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, auth0, okta, returnurl

ASP.NET MVC's feature to append a query string value before authentication, with the name ReturnUrl, seems to be lost when OpenId Connect based authentication is implemented.

For example, I hit a route as '/product/edit/404', if I am not authenticated, ASP.NET framework would ask me to log in. And the new URL would be like '/account/login?ReturnUrl=/product/edit/404'.

Upon successful login, I get automatically get redirected to '/product/edit/404', instead of the default route, which would generally be like '/home/index'.

After integrating OpenId Connect based authentication, I seem to have lost this ability/feature.

Any experts know how to get this working again?

Comment: What ASP.NET version and libraries are these?

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla: ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 and latest OWIN libs